# Matlab: Dividing chunks of data randomly into equal sized sets

Tags: matlab, range, indices

I have a large dataset that I need to divide randomly into 5 almost equal sized sets for cross validation. I have happily used `_crossvalind_` to divide into sets before, however this time I need to divide chunks of data into these groups at a time.

Let's say my data looks like this:

```
data = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18];
```

Then I want to divide them randomly into 5 groups in chunks of 2, e.g. like this

```
g1 = [3 4], [11 12]  
g2 = [9 10]  
g3 = [1 2], [15 16]  
g4 = [7 8], [17 18]  
g5 = [5 6], [13 14]
```

I think I can do this with some for-loops, but I'm guessing there must be a much more cost-efficient way to do it in matlab :-)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm interpreting your needs to be random ordering of sets, but within each set, the ordering of elements is unchanged from the parent set. You can use `randperm` to randomly order the number of sets and use linear indexing for the elements.

```
dataElements=numel(data);%# get number of elements
totalGroups=5;
groupSize=dataElements/totalGroups;%# I'm assuming here that it's neatly divisible as in your example
randOrder=randperm(totalGroups);%# randomly order of numbers from 1 till totalGroups
g=reshape(data,groupSize,totalGroups)';             %'# SO formatting
g=g(randOrder,:);
```

The different rows of `g` give you the different groupings.

Comment: @R. M.: Your last line is a bit on the complicated side. Why not replace it by: `g = reshape(data,groupSize,totalGroups)'; g = g(randOrder,:);`

Comment: @Jonas: thanks, you're right; that was complicated! i've replaced the line.

Comment: @R. M.: Now it looks like what I'd have answered. +1 :)

Comment: I think I might have explained my problem wrongly, or I just can't see yet that this is exactly what I need :) I will try to look at my problem and figure out if this is what I needed. Thanks :)

Comment: Now I edited my description of the problem. As far is I understand randperm() wouldn't work for a problem like that, or am i wrong

Comment: @danielhc, you can use the same algorithm to do that. so instead of 5 groups with 2 sub-groups of 2 elements in each, you can first divide it into 10 groups of 2 elements and take every 2 rows as your data. if you have to leave one group with a single sub-group (as in `g2`), then just pad your data vector with 2 `NaN`s or `0`s at the end, do as I just mentioned, and then remove the `NaN`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can shuffle the array (randperm) and then divide it into consequentive equal parts.

```
data = [10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120 130 140 150];
permuted = data(randperm(length(data)));
% padding may be required if the length of data is not divisible by the size of chunks
k = 5;
g = reshape(permuted, k, length(data)/k);
```