# matlab: dividing vector into overlapping chunks of fixed size

Tags: matlab, vector, split, range, indices

I've a vector that I would like to split into overlapping subvectors of size `cs` in shifts of `sh`. Imagine the input vector is:

```
v=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13]; % A=[1:13]
```

given a `chunksize` of 4 (`cs=4`) and shift of 2 (`sh=2`), the result should look like:

```
[1 2 3 4]
[3 4 5 6]
[5 6 7 8]
[7 8 9 10]
[9 10 11 12]
```

note that the input vector is not necessarily divisible by the `chunksize` and therefore some subvectors are discarded. Is there any fast way to compute that, without the need of using e.g. a `for` loop?
In a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525186/matlab-dividing-chunks-of-data-randomly-into-equal-sized-sets) I found how to do that but when considering non-overlapping subvectors.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the function [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html%E2%80%8E) in the following manner:

```
v=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13]; % A=[1:13]
cs=4;
sh=2;

A = v(bsxfun(@plus,(1:cs),(0:sh:length(v)-cs)'));
```

Here is how it works. `bsxfun` applies some basic functions on 2 arrays and performs some `repmat`-like if the sizes of inputs do not fit. In this case, I generate the indexes of the first chunk, and add the offset of each chunck. As one input is a row-vector and the other is a column-vector, the result is a matrix. Finally, when indexing a vector with a matrix, the result is a matrix, that is precisely what you expect.

And it is a one-liner, (almost) always fun :).

Comment: Try it with `cs = 5;sh = 2;`, will give you three and NOT two (two would be correct as sh=2) overlapping entries

Comment: @bjoern As I mentioned in the comment to your question, your solution indeed gives a different outcome. However, that does not neccesarily mean it is correct.

Comment: Okay, now I see what you are refering to. I was 100% sure that `sh` described the number of overlapping entries, but now I see that you both refer to it as another measure. Sorry my fault, really must have missed that Oo And I'm only NOW seeing that the description isn't unique as the posted example is ambiguous

Comment: one-liner `bsxfun` (almost) always deserves +1!

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the signal processing toolbox?  Then the command is `buffer`.  First look at the bare output:

```
buffer(v, 4, 2)

ans =
     0     1     3     5     7     9    11
     0     2     4     6     8    10    12
     1     3     5     7     9    11    13
     2     4     6     8    10    12     0
```

That's clearly the right idea, with only a little tuning necessary to give you exactly the output you want:

```
[y z] = buffer(v, 4, 2, 'nodelay');
y.'

ans =
     1     2     3     4
     3     4     5     6
     5     6     7     8
     7     8     9    10
     9    10    11    12
```

That said, consider leaving the vectors columnwise, as that better matches most use cases.  For example, the mean of each window is just `mean` of the matrix, as columnwise is the default.

Comment: I like the use of these little gems that no one knew it was in a toolbox already. The problem is that it can leave you with partial data in the last frame but it depends what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the simplest way is actually with a loop.
A vectorizes solution can be faster, but if the result is properly preallocated the loop should perform decently as well.

```
v = 1:13
cs = 4;
sh = 2;

myMat = NaN(floor((numel(v) - cs) / sh) + 1,cs);
count = 0;

for t = cs:sh:numel(v)
   count = count+1;
   myMat(count,:) = v(t-cs+1:t);
end
```

Comment: I don't see why this should be necessary, especially as Tin asked for a solution without `for`-loop.

Comment: @bjoern: I agree with Dennis, his solution is just simpler. Arrayfun is basically also a for loop, and in this case even significantly slower.

Comment: @bjoern Note that arrayfun is pretty much just a wrapper for a loop (and thus will not really outperform the simple loop).

Comment: Yeah it might as well be a for-loop but written in C and not in MATLAB, and if performance doesn't matter it might also be a matter of code complexity and code-nesting where the question-author likes to have a shorter code. Whatsoever, I simply posted what the author asked for ;-)

Comment: Oh okay, he asked for a fast way and didn't specifically state anything about a short-code. So okay then..

Comment: Dennis, I think you've still got an error in your code -> `v(t-3:t);` what is this supposed to be? I mean there's something about `cs` missing in it, right now you are always fetching 3 entries which is wrong

Comment: That's what I first changed as well to correct it but something is still wrong with it, `cs = 5; sh = 2;` gives me three overlapping entries in the matrix and not 2

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: I believe the way you calculate the number of chunks is not correct, see my answer. You calculate the number of rows to preallocate for `myMat` based on `sh` only, while it should also include `cs`. For `cs = 10` and `sh = 2`, it should only produce 2 rows, while in your case it preallocates 5 rows.

Comment: @BasSwinckels Thanks, that part felt a bit dodgy.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with `ndgrid`:

```
>> v=1:13; cs=4; sh=2;
>> [Y,X]=ndgrid(1:(cs-sh):(numel(v)-cs+1),0:cs-1)
>> chunks = X+Y
chunks =
     1     2     3     4
     3     4     5     6
     5     6     7     8
     7     8     9    10
     9    10    11    12
```

The nice thing about the [second syntax of the `colon` operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) (`j:i:k`) is that you don't have to calculate `k` exactly (e.g. `1:2:6` gives `[1 3 5]`) if you plan to discard the extra entries, as in this problem. It automatically goes to `j+m*i`, where `m = fix((k-j)/i)`;

Different test:

```
>> v=1:14; cs=5; sh=2; % or v=1:15 or v=1:16
>> [Y,X]=ndgrid(1:(cs-sh):(numel(v)-cs+1),0:cs-1); chunks = X+Y
chunks =
     1     2     3     4     5
     4     5     6     7     8
     7     8     9    10    11
    10    11    12    13    14
```

And a new row will form with `v=1:17`. Does this handle all cases as needed?

Answer (score 0):

What about this? First I generate the starting-indices based on `cs` and `sh` for slicing the single vectors out of the full-length vector, then I delete all indices for which `idx+cs` would exceed the vector length and then I'm slicing out the single sub-vectors via `arrayfun` and afterwards converting them into a matrix:

```
v=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13]; % A=[1:13]
cs=4;
sh=2;

idx = 1:(cs-sh):length(v);
idx = idx(idx+cs-1 <= length(v))
A = arrayfun(@(i) v(i:(i+cs-1)), idx, 'UniformOutput', false);
cell2mat(A')
```

E.g. for `cs=5; sh=3;` this would give:

```
idx =

     1     3     5     7


ans =

     1     2     3     4     5
     3     4     5     6     7
     5     6     7     8     9
     7     8     9    10    11
```

Depending on where the values `cs; sh` come from, you'd probably want to introduce a simple error-check so that `cs > 0;` as well as `sh < cs`. `sh < 0` would be possible theoretically if you'd want to leave some values out in between.

**EDIT**: Fixed a very small bug, should be running for different combinations of sh and cs now.

Comment: Why should I? It works with different numbers as well. `idx` is only supposed to give me the starting indices of the subvectors and therefore, I def. need cs-sh as the step - EDIT: I tried using different vectors and different numbers of `cs` and `sh` and it works quite nicely.

Comment: For `cs=5; sh=3` I would assume the starting indices to be `1 4 7` rather than `1 3 5 7`. If this is the case one would use `idx=1:sh:length(v)`.

Comment: Sorry but I got to tell you, that's wrong. Just rethink about it. `1 3 5 7` are the correct indices - just look at my output matrix which obviously IS correct (length of 5 (i.e. 5 columns) as you can clearly see, which is the chunksize cs=5) and three overlapping entries (the last three entries of each row are the three first entries of the next row)