# splitting string into even and odd segment in matlab

Tags: string, matlab

I'm working with MATLAB and I want to read string from a .txt file and then want to split that string into even and odd segments (based on the position of characters).

For example, "hello," then the result should be:

```
Segment 1 = "hlo" & segment 2 = "el"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A string is just a character array, so you can use the [colon operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) as you would a numerical array:

```
>> str = 'hello'
str =
hello
>> s1 = str(1:2:end)
s1 =
hlo
>> s2 = str(2:2:end)
s2 =
el
```

Notice that it is unnecessary to use `end-1` for either string because `colon` computes the last index based on the skip and start index, thus you don't need to worry about the length of `str`. It's a convenient feature in many situations (further details and different example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20621298/2778484)).