# matlab: splitting images into overlapping blocks

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, overlap

I've an image of size `[M,N]`, which I would like to split into `overlapping` blocks of size `[rr,cc]`. Each block is shifted by `yy` and `xx` pixels. The code below does the job. Is there any more efficient way to do that? e.g. avoiding the `for` loops? The solutions that I found [approach #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109360/segment-the-image-into-blocks/20109476#20109476) or [approach #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238828/is-there-a-substitute-for-blockproc-in-matlab) where mainly for `non-overlapping` blocks.

**SOL 1**

```
Im = imread('cameraman.tif');
[M,N,~] = size(Im);
rr = 64; cc = 64; xx = 32; yy = 32;

numBlocksYY = numel(1:rr-xx:(M-(rr-1)));
numBlocksXX = numel(1:cc-yy:(N-(cc-1)));
[numBlocksYY, numBlocksXX]
C = cell(numBlocksYY*numBlocksXX,1);
counter = 1;
for ii=1:rr-xx:(M-(rr-1))
    for jj=1:cc-yy:(N-(cc-1))
        fprintf('[%d:%d, %d:%d]\n',ii,ii+rr-1,jj,jj+cc-1);
        C{counter} =  Im(ii:(ii+rr-1), jj:(jj+cc-1), : );
        counter = counter + 1;
    end
    fprintf('\n');
end

figure;
for ii=1:numBlocksYY*numBlocksXX
    subplot(numBlocksYY,numBlocksYY,ii), imagesc( C{ii} ); axis image; colormap gray;
end
```

**SOL 2**
Inspired by some of the solutions proposed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609694/matlab-dividing-vector-into-overlapping-chunks-of-fixed-size), I tried to come to a solution using `ndgrid`, but how could I later on fill the output `cell C` and access to the sub-images using the `XX` and `YY` indexes? I'm also curious to see if there are any other solutions :-) ?

```
[YY,XX]=ndgrid( 1:(rr-xx):(M-(rr-1)) , 1:(cc-yy):(N-(cc-1)));
```

Comment: Tried BLOCKPROC? http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/blockproc.html

Comment: @Divakar, thank you, but I just want to later on save those subimages into disk, i.e. I don't want to apply any `function` into the blocks ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the output `cell C` from `XX` and `YY` given in **SOL 2** as follows:

```
% indices of the first rr x cc block
IDX1 = bsxfun(@plus, (1:rr)', ((1:cc)-1)*M);
% offset in indices for each block
offset = (XX(:)-1) + (YY(:)-1)*M;
% indices of each block, the block is indexed with the 3rd dimension
IDX = bsxfun(@plus, IDX1, reshape(offset, [1 1 numel(offset)]));
% convert to cell of blocks
C = mat2cell(Im(IDX), rr, cc, ones(1, numel(XX)));
```

Comment: How can this excellent solution be extended to multi-channel images (e.g. RGB)?