# Blockproc and for loop method of split of image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I'm learning how to split an image into overlapping blocks of 8x8 and overlap by 4 pixels.

Using blockproc(), i can accomplish this easily where:

```
T = dctmtx(8);
dct = @(block_struct) T * block_struct.data * T';
B1 = blockproc(I, [4 4], dct, 'BorderSize',[2 2], 'TrimBorder', false, 'PadPartialBlocks',true)
```

But the problem is that blockproc() requires a function to work in this case its "dct" which is performed on each block created.

Instead I'm trying to use a **for loop** to just **split the image without any function to each yet.**

Would appreciate some help on this.

**Edit i tried writing the for loop method, but i'm not certain it's correct, since it doesn't use borders unlike the blockproc method.

```
%% Read in image file
camera = imread('cameraman.tif');
camera = im2double(camera);
[hor,ver,color] = size(camera); %256x256 image
imshow(camera)

%% Set the specifications of the blocks
rblock = 8; %each block will occupy 8 pixels 
cblock = 8;
xpix = 4; %this will be our jump in the for loop
cpix = 4;

%% Compute how many blocks in row and column

whole_row = numel(1:rblock-xpix:(hor-(rblock-1))); 
whole_col = numel(1:cblock-cpix:(ver-(cblock-1)));

%% Create a cell array to store the blocked images
ca = cell(whole_row*whole_col,1); 
ca = reshape(ca, whole_row,whole_col); %reshape to 63x63

%% Scan through the image and extract each blocks
ind = 1;
for row = 1: rblock-xpix: (hor-(rblock-1))
    for col = 1: cblock-cpix : (ver-(cblock-1))
        row1 = row;
        row2 = row1 + rblock-1;

        col1 = col;
        col2 = col1 + cblock-1;

        ca{ind} = camera(row1:row2, col1:col2,:);
        ind = ind + 1;
    end
end

%% View the block images
ind = 1;
numPlotsR = size(ca,1); % 63
numPlotsC = size(ca,2); % 63

set(gcf,'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
drawnow;

for r =1: numPlotsR
    for c = 1: numPlotsC
        subplot(numPlotsR, numPlotsC, ind);
        rgbBlock = ca{c,r};
        imshow(rgbBlock)
        ind = ind + 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: Please show your attempt, and why you are not able to do it using for loops. Look at [indexing in Matlab](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html). What would be wrong with a function that just returns its input argument, e.g. `dct = @(bock_struct) block_struct.data;`?

Comment: @rinkert I've updated the post on my attempt. Could you look into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is working fine, in selecting blocks. You are using linear indexing to place the blocks in the cell array, which you are doing in the 'wrong' order. You are now filling the columns of the cell array with one row of blocks from the image. Either transpose the cell array, or use the following loop:

```
%% Create a cell array to store the blocked images
ca = cell(whole_row, whole_col);  % no need for reshape

%% Scan through the image and extract each blocks
row_start_indices = 1: rblock-xpix: (hor-(rblock-1))
col_start_indices = 1: cblock-cpix : (ver-(cblock-1))
for ri = 1:numel(row_start_indices);
    for ci = 1:numel(col_start_indices)
        row1 = row_start_indices(ri);
        row2 = row1 + rblock-1;

        col1 = col_start_indices(ci);
        col2 = col1 + cblock-1;

        ca{ri,ci} = camera(row1:row2, col1:col2,:);
    end
end
```

---

As you pointed out, above does not give the exact same result as `blockproc`. This has to do with the way `blockproc` is sampling from the image. You specify a 4-by-4 block, with a border of 2 pixels, meaning that the first block taken from the image are the first 4-by-4 pixels top left, with a border of two additional pixels in each direction. You specify `PadPartialBlocks` to be true, so the top left will be padded with zeros, since there is no image data that can be used for the border.

So to get the results to match, you can pad your image, so that the for loop takes the same blocks as `blockproc`:

```
%% Read in image file
camera = imread('cameraman.tif');
camera = im2double(camera);

%% use blockproc
T = eye(8); % create transformation that does not transform
dct = @(block_struct) T * block_struct.data * T';
B1 = blockproc(camera, [4 4], dct, 'BorderSize',[2 2], 'TrimBorder', false, 'PadPartialBlocks',false);

% pad image, and get new dimensions
pad_size = 2;
camera = padarray(camera, [pad_size pad_size]); % pad 2 pixel wide border in all directions
[hor,ver,color] = size(camera); %256x256 + something image

%% Set the specifications of the blocks
rblock = 8; %each block will occupy 8 pixels 
cblock = 8;
xpix = 4; %this will be our jump in the for loop
cpix = 4;

%% Compute how many blocks in row and column
whole_row = numel(1:rblock-xpix:(hor-(rblock-1))); 
whole_col = numel(1:cblock-cpix:(ver-(cblock-1)));

%% Create a cell array to store the blocked images
ca = cell(whole_row, whole_col);  % no need for reshape

%% Scan through the image and extract each blocks
row_start_indices = 1: rblock-xpix: (hor-(rblock-1));
col_start_indices = 1: cblock-cpix : (ver-(cblock-1));
for ri = 1:numel(row_start_indices);
    for ci = 1:numel(col_start_indices)
        row1 = row_start_indices(ri);
        row2 = row1 + rblock-1;

        col1 = col_start_indices(ci);
        col2 = col1 + cblock-1;

        ca{ri,ci} = camera(row1:row2, col1:col2,:);
    end
end

% convert the cell array to a matrix
camera2 = cell2mat(ca);

% compare resutls of blockproc and for-loop:
isEqual = all(all(camera2==B1));

% get rid of the border:
img_out = camera2(pad_size+1:end-pad_size, pad_size+1:end-pad_size);
```

Comment: thank you. but my problem still remains. if you take "dct2(ca{1})" and compare with the output dct matrix of the blockproc() above, the first 8 row and column are different. may i know why is it that the for loop split and blockproc split result in different dct matrix?

Comment: i realized something, if you take a look at the "Workspace" tab at the lower right, you'll see that B1 which is the matrix of the blockproc is 512x512 which is the result of (64x8,64x8) but the ca cell array is only 63x63 = (63x8,63x8) which is 504x504. Apparently the calculation of the line of code "whole_row = numel(1:rblock-xpix:(hor-(rblock-1))); " is resulting in the 63 which i referred through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271101/matlab-splitting-images-into-overlapping-blocks . Is there any issue with this equation?

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanation on the process! I understand now. Cheers!